# Wss4jSecurityInterceptor Class not found error

Tags: java, spring, web-services, maven, soap

I want to use `org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor` in my web application. In `pom.xml` I have added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

dependency property. But In the spring configuration it says 'org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor' Not found. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor at http://www.findjar.com/ I see it is present on this maven location:  http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/springframework/ws/spring-ws-security/1.5.6/spring-ws-security-1.5.6.jar

that should be

```
<groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
<version>1.5.6</version>
```

There are probably other versions to, but it is a totally different artifact. To be sure, just look if the missing class is actually present in the jar you expect it to be present.

Comment: Actually, I just had a quick look and I see the class is not there: jar tf ~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/ws/spring-ws-core/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-ws-core-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar | grep Wss4jSecurityInterceptor

Answer (score 0):

You need to **use 3.1.8 or later for java 8 or 4.0.10 for java 11**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Check actual maven dependency : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ws/spring-ws-security